# ApacheSolr - Create Custom Field Bias

Tags: 7, entities, search

I'm trying to create a new Field Bias with the *ApacheSolr* module. It's a field I've called *References*, and it's associated with only certain types (articles, pages, etc.).

Because I'm also using the *ApacheSolr* Module, I'd like to be able to index this new field.

Here's my existing code attempting to accomplish this:

```
function footnotes_apachesolr_index_document_build(ApacheSolrDocument &$document, $entity, $entity_type)
{
    if($entity_type == 'node')
        $document->addField('ts_references', $entity->references[$entity->language][0]['value']);
}

function footnotes_apachesolr_query_alter(DrupalSolrQueryInterface $query)
{
    $query->addParam('qf', 'ts_references');
}

function footnotes_apachesolr_field_name_map_alter(&$map)
{
    $map['ts_references'] = t('Footnotes explained typically at the Bottom of the Article');
}
```

From all of the tutorials I've followed, this is the correct code for Drupal 7.

Here's some additional details, in case you need to know:

- The Module is named *Footnotes*, and the Field is named *References*.
- The website I'm working on supports multiple languages
- The *References* Field Definition type is `text_long`
- The *References* Field Instance Definition type is `text_textarea`.

For reasons unknown to me, this isn't working. When I look at all of the Field Biases in the Configuration Menu, mine is not listed there. I'm simply wanting to know how to fix that.

Let me know if you need any additional information to figure this one out. I'll add it to this post.